# how to identify a hard drive (drive letter) that is on the primary IDE channel in windows xp

Tags: visual-c++

I would like get drive letter to create a file for data writing. This drive in on primary IDE channel as master. in the system I have another drive in (secondary IDE as slave )which has OS installed in it.

I use GetDriveType() when it returns "removable" I use that to create files. But not all the drives show up as removable. is there a other way this can be accomplished?

my goal is to identify what drive letter is assigned to the CF flash drive. it is in the primary IDE channel as master. The problem I am having now not all the CF cards as "removable". I can't rely on windows because it doesn't assign same drive letter every time it boots. 
Therefore I need to way to find this drive letter.

Comment: A hard drive will never show up as 'removable' because they are not removable by definition. Your question therefore doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you perhaps rephrase it a different way? Why not just ask the user to specify the location of a scratch disk?

Comment: @CodyGray Google [removable ide hard drive bay](https://www.google.ca/#q=removable+ide+hard+drive+bay).  They are not normally *hot-swappable*, though.

Comment: @artless I'm pretty sure that the GetDriveType() function will still return that such a disk is fixed, not removable. Could be wrong, haven't ever tested it.

Comment: @CodyGray Sorry, I missed your point; I was just fixated on *not removable by definition*.  There is no hardware on *IDE* to know that it is a *removeable* device.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you, but you can use the `GetWindowsDirectory` method to determine the path that Windows is installed on (say, "C:\windows").  From that you can determine that the `C:\` drive has the operating system, which in your case, may be the primary drive.

Here's the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724454%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: This will only tell you which drive Windows is installed on. It doesn't tell you anything about which drive is on the primary channel, or which drive is the master. If you're going to just assume that the system disk is the primary master, then you might as well just assume that the primary master is always drive `C:`. You'll be right just about as often.